# Build has just started asking for an archivebasename?

Tags: gradle, gretty

GRADLE build that has been running fine, no changes that I can see to the gradle configs, has recently started erroring with

Could not set unknown property 'archiveBaseName' for task ':archiveProduct' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip.

What is the solution to this? Using Gretty, if that is useful.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is gretty 3.0.2 update. Please do not use gretty 3.0.2, just use gretty 3.0.1 and below.

If you have the maven import `classpath 'org.gretty:gretty:+'` you will need to hard code 3.0.2 there